# Can we change the layout of iPad drop down?

Tags: ipad

Can we change the layout of iPad drop down? for eg. can we use colors or make the options bold? Need to know as CSS change does not get replicated on iPad, no matter what...

Comment: You can target any device based on screen resolution. You need to look into media queries.

Comment: No. I am not talking about screen resolutions. Just need to know whether we can customize the drop down(Add colors or change layout) in iPad.

Comment: Generally drop down are pain to style. Use some javascript/jquery based plugin?

Comment: yes...thats the last option i see..Thanks Gurpreet